# SSIS update varchar containing gibberish

Tags: oracle, unicode, ssis, try-catch

I have a DB2 table that I bring to oracle using SSIS.
This table apperantly has varchar columns that can contain jibberish with characters like ®, and then the load fails trying to store these bad values in a varchar.

I've solved this by changing the destination field in oracle to be Nvarchar, which is unicode and handles the "bad" characters as well.

However, this is not enough, because the process continues to other tools that can't handle the gibberish.

My objective, is to identify these fields on-the-fly in SSIS/Oracle and update them to be NULL.

A. Is there a way in ORACLE, to check if a string contains characters that char/varchar data types won't accept?

B. Is there a way in SSIS to try/catch bad FIELDS conversions and UPDATE these fields, instead of throwing the record to a different table?

Thank you!! Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please  [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: how did they get into the base in first place, if you know what you load you can actually correct the information.

Comment: They have an option of loading an excel file. It's another system in our organization. We take the data from it into our dedicated data architecture and tables for different statistical analysis